# change background color in open3d.visualization.draw_geometries

Tags: python, colors, background, open3d

I want to change the background color in Open3D when I draw geometries using `open3d.visualization.draw_geometries`, but I can't figure out how to that, as [the documentation](http://www.open3d.org/docs/release/python_api/open3d.visualization.draw_geometries.html) is not showing how to do it.

can you please tell me how can I change background color please? or show `Skymap` or example? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`open3d.visualization.draw_geometries` is a small wrapper function that calls `open3d.visualization.Visualizer` class methods. For customizing the rendering options, you will have to move to using `Visualizer` class directly which allows finer control on rendering and view control options.

Now, to change background color, you can use Visualizer as below:-

```
import open3d as o3d

ply_point_cloud = o3d.data.PLYPointCloud()
pcd = o3d.io.read_point_cloud(ply_point_cloud.path)

vis = o3d.visualization.Visualizer()
vis.create_window(visible=True)
# Call only after creating visualizer window.
vis.get_render_option().background_color = [0, 0, 1]
vis.add_geometry(pcd)
vis.run()
```

[image: Result of setting RGB as (0,0,1)]

Comment: BTW, you can write your own version of `draw_geometries` which adds multiple geometries to Visualizer class, however I would recommend to use Visualizer class as it allows for non-blocking visualization which is very helpful when working with streaming data.