How to change the background in Open3d for clound point?
import open3d as o3d

ply_point_cloud = o3d.data.PLYPointCloud()
pcd = o3d.io.read_point_cloud(ply_point_cloud.path)

vis = o3d.visualization.Visualizer()
vis.create_window(visible=True)
# Call only after creating visualizer window.
vis.get_render_option().background_color = [0, 0, 1]
vis.add_geometry(pcd)
vis.run()

I got this code from Stackoverflow, still this was not working in my case.
Can someone help me please....
When I run the code all i see is a loading white blank page

Answer taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/77506153/1874627. @Harikrishnan - Check version of open3d. If I remember correctly, version 0.17.0 only returned copy of RenderOption when calling get_render_option(). Hence changes made to RenderOption object didnt make any changes to Visualizer. Upgrade to Version 0.18.0.

I have installed open3d 0.18.0
/n
C:\Users\USER>pip show open3d
Name: open3d
Version: 0.18.0
Summary: Open3D: A Modern Library for 3D Data Processing.
Home-page: https://www.open3d.org
Author: Open3D Team
Author-email: info@open3d.org
License: MIT

Try running this:
print(vis.get_render_option().background_color)
vis.get_render_option().background_color = [0, 0, 1]
print(vis.get_render_option().background_color)

If the new value is not blue, open3d behavious on Windows is incorrect.
